# Vue router keep-alive and mounted behavior

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I had some logic in the `mounted()` method before I started using `<keep-alive>`. For instance: `document.title = this.title`. Now the title changes upon the first load only.

I could listen for route changes, but it won't work when you land on the page.

What is the proper way to detect loading of another component in `<keep-alive>`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Move your logic to the [`activated`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#activated) lifecycle hook, which is called whenever a keep-alive component is activated.

For example:

```
new Vue({
  ...
  activated: function() {
    document.title = this.title;
  },
  ...
});
```

Comment: Game changer! Thank you!!